# My MongoDB logging system behaves different from expected. Why?

Tags: java

I am working on a MongoDB logging system, but it doesn't do behave as I expected.I don't know if the structure of the program is fine.
I want to search in the database (MongoDB) and print all the events, but when I have a `pageLoad` event I want to check if it has a `URL` and to print it, else it should search again for the next event and attempt the same behavior, as a loop.

The result I expected would have to be like this, for example:

- mouseMove
- mouseMove
- mouseMove
- click
- scroll
- click
- pageLoad....//htttp://www......url(1).....e.x
- mouseMove
- click
- pageLoad....//htttp://www......url(2).....e.x

---

This is the code:

```
MongoClient mongoClient;
DB db;

mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
db = mongoClient.getDB("behaviourDB_areas");    

DBCollection cEvent = db.getCollection("event");

    BasicDBObject orderBy = new BasicDBObject();
    orderBy.put("timeStamp",1);

    DBCursor cursorEvents = null;

    BasicDBObject searchQuery = new BasicDBObject();
    searchQuery.put("user_id", "55b20db905f333defea9827f");

    cursorEvents = cEvent.find(searchQuery).sort(orderBy);

    while (cursorEvents.hasNext()) {
        DBObject documentInEventCollection = cursorEvents.next();

        System.out.println(cursorEvents.next().get("type").toString());

        if ("pageLoad".equals(documentInEventCollection.get("type"))) {

            System.out.println(cursorEvents.next().get("url").toString());
        } else {

            System.out.println(cursorEvents.next().get("type").toString());             
       }                
   }
    mongoClient.close();
```

---

But when I run the program, the result I get is like this, for example:

- windowSize
- mouseMove
- clickUp
- click

...And it stops there.

---

What is wrong?

Comment: Add a try-catch around your while() loop and print out any exceptions you might get.

Comment: Please read - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `cursorEvents.next()` three times in the loop, instead of just once. Every time you call next(), you go... to the next element.

Use your `documentInEventCollection` variable instead:

```
while (cursorEvents.hasNext()) {
    DBObject documentInEventCollection = cursorEvents.next();

    System.out.println(documentInEventCollection.get("type").toString());

    if ("pageLoad".equals(documentInEventCollection.get("type"))) {

        System.out.println(documentInEventCollection.get("url").toString());
    } else {

        System.out.println(documentInEventCollection.get("type").toString());             
   }
```

}